# wrong direction to an equation below a tagged one

Tags: equations, labels, ref

I put a tag into an equation for example:

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq1} \tag{A}
a = b
\end{Equation}
```

Below this equation I have other numbered equations, lets call one of them \label{eq2}.

On the next pages, when I click a reference to eq2, it shows the text above eq1.
How to deal with that?
Top

Comment: it is always best to provide a complete small document that shows the problem. Presumably your real document has `equation `not `Equation` and has defined `\tag` using `amsmath`  and is using `hyperref` to make links active.

Comment: it would be more natural to have `\tag`  before the `\label` but without a test file I'm not sure if that's the only issue.

Comment: I remember the issue, it should work by using the starred environment `equation*` for the equation with `\tag` but I can't find the reference right now...

Comment: The method with equation* works, thank you.